# Why assigning list containing array to array itself causes recursion in perl?

Tags: arrays, list, perl, recursion

I'm using DBIX::Class and generating conditions for search like that:

```
my @array;
push @array, { condition1 => 'value1' };
push @array, [ { condition2 => 'value2' }, { condition3 => 'value3' } ];
```

All this conditions must be checked using **AND** operator, that's why I wrote this:

```
@array = ( -and => @array );
```

After running code with such conditions process on my virtual machine started to use up to 8 Gb memory. I thought that it was recursion problems and I didn't mistake. I checked logs and saw records about **deep recursion** but I couldn't find anything about my case in internet.

Is there problems with assigning list containing array to array itself?
Or maybe it is a problem with DBIX::Class (SQL::Abstract)? Why it causes deep recursion?

Update. This is the real code from project:

```
sub faq {
    my ( $self ) = @_;
    my @cond;

    if ( $self->param('faq_type') ) {
        push @cond,
        {
            'me.faq_type' => $self->param('faq_type'),
        };
    }

    if ( my $search = $self->param('search') ) {
        push @cond,
        [
            'me.title' => { ilike => "%$search%" },
            'me.text'  => { ilike => "%$search%" },
        ];
    }

    @cond = ( -and => @cond );

    my %attr = (
        join         => 'page_category',
        rows         => $self->param('limit'),
        offset       => $self->param('offset'),
        order_by     => { -desc => 'id' },
        result_class => 'BUX::Util::HashRefInflator',
        '+select'    => [ qw( page_category.name ) ],
        '+as'        => [ qw( category_name ) ],
    );

    my @pages       = BUX::DB->rs('Page')->search( \@cond, \%attr )->all;
    my $total_count = BUX::DB->rs('Page')->count( \@cond );

    return $self->render(json => {
        pages => \@pages,
        count => $total_count
    });
}
```

And log records:

Deep recursion on subroutine "SQL::Abstract::_SWITCH_refkind" at /opt/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.14.4/lib/site_perl/5.14.4/SQL/Abstract.pm line 719.
Deep recursion on subroutine "SQL::Abstract::_recurse_where" at /opt/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.14.4/lib/site_perl/5.14.4/SQL/Abstract.pm line 546.
Deep recursion on subroutine "SQL::Abstract::_where_ARRAYREF" at /opt/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.14.4/lib/site_perl/5.14.4/SQL/Abstract.pm line 687.
Deep recursion on subroutine "SQL::Abstract::_where_HASHREF" at /opt/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.14.4/lib/site_perl/5.14.4/SQL/Abstract.pm line 493.
Deep recursion on subroutine "SQL::Abstract::_where_unary_op" at /opt/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.14.4/lib/site_perl/5.14.4/SQL/Abstract.pm line 596.
Deep recursion on subroutine "SQL::Abstract::_where_op_ANDOR" at /opt/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.14.4/lib/site_perl/5.14.4/SQL/Abstract.pm line 645.

P.S. `BUX::DB` is the subclass of `DBIx::Class` and `rs` is a shortcut for `resultset`.

Comment: Please show more of your code.  The `@array = (-and => @array);` is the same as `@array = ('-and', @array);` and merely prepends the string `-and` to `@array`; it's not recursive. (I don't know see how that helps with your need for the _operator_ `and`)

Comment: Yeah, I know that is a string. Fat comma stringifies left hand operand. I am thinking the same about this assignment. If I am not mistaken array in list context behaves exactly as a list.

After generating conditions I do nothing more than:
`$schema->resultset('Table')->search(\@array);`

That's it.

Comment: It comes strange to me but looks like @JimGarrison said. However perl's arrays are diferent from arrays in another languages. If I wanted to add a reference to array into array itself I would wrote something like this:
`@array = ( -and => \@array);`
\ is used for getting references in perl.

Comment: @zdim oh, by the way, I'm curious why it causes recursion just like you. I don't need recursion in my code. I just needed to prepend '-and' into my array. And now I just want to understand how this code `@array = ( -and => @array );` can cause recursion.

Comment: @JimGarrison [demo](http://tpcg.io/ZxOV2L) - in this example you can see that there is no recursive structure created. Perl uses arrays as lists in such cases.

Comment: My point was that you need to show more of your code.  As I said, `@array = (-and => @array);` _itself_ prepends `'-and'` to array, no recursion. The array does get flattened into list as you said. If you assign `\@array` then that's what it adds.  But we don't see what the rest of the code does.

Comment: Just once more: I suggest that you show (far?) more code, and certainly sections that actually draw that error.  If it's too much to dump here then do your part and build a simplified version that exhibits the same problem.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, runnable demonstration of the problem. (See [mcve].) You say your problem is that you have code that performs endless recursion, but you have not shown anything that performs any recursion.

Comment: @Jim Garrison, Re "*`@array` contains a reference to itself*", No, it doesn't. Your whole comment is incorrect.

Comment: It seems to me you want to push `{ condition2 => 'value2' }, ...`, not `[{condition2 => ...}, {...}]` to get an array of hashrefs. You should then specify `search({ -and => \@array })` and be good to go.

Comment: You probably have that code in a loop, so your array grows more and more. Please [edit] and show us a lot more, or we cannot help you.

Comment: I added code just as you asked. Hope that it will be helpful.

Comment: `'me.faq_type' => $self->param('faq_type')` looks like it may be vulnerable to injection. Where does `param` come from?

Comment: This question is useless without a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, but it is complete example of code. There is nothing to add. It's totally complete. As you can see this part of code is the separate mojo controller and I checked it before writing questions here. Only this part of code causes such problems and changing it solves problems.

Comment: Re:"`'me.faq_type' => $self->param('faq_type')` looks like it may be vulnerable to injection." - no it's not. DBIx::Class uses SQL::Abstract which uses sql parameters when generates sql. Summary, ORM handles such things for us.

Comment: I am quite certain melpomene is right in that there's a problem there, though I'm struggling to remember the specifics. I would suggest `$c->req->params->{faq_type}` instead. `param()` accepts lists of parameters, which you do not need here, anyway.

Comment: I can't find anything about problems with using `param` method and can't find any post about benefits of using `$c->req->params` method too. As I had seen the most mojo-way method of getting parameters is Mojolicious::Controller's `param` method.

Answer (score 0):

When specifying several conditions that should all be met to search
with DBIx::Class, the usual way to do this is by passing a hashref
with the column names as keys and the conditions as values.

While it is possible to instead specify an arrayref of hashrefs with the '-and' keyword, this is most often unnecessary - especially if you only have one condition to specify!

NOTE: I am not certain `{ -and => @cond }` does what you want, have you tried replacing it with `{ -and => \@cond }` ( Note the array**ref**) ? This could be the reason why SQL::Abstract gets confused, though I'm unsure how that would end up being a recursion.

SECOND NOTE: I find `@cond = ( -and => \@cond )` confusing and it may cause trouble. I would suggest working with a hashref passed into search, as it should be called with, and setting the `-and` key instead, by adapting my first example.

This is how I would specify the conditions:

```
my $cond;

if ( my $faq_type = $self->param('faq_type') ){
    $cond->{'me.faq_type'} = $faq_type;
}

if ( my $search = $self->param('search') ){
    $cond->{-or} = [
        { $cond->{'me.title'} = { ilike => '%$search%' }, },
        { $cond->{'me.text' } = { ilike => '%$search%' }, },
    ];
}
```

An alternative to consider, would be to first specify the 'faq_type' search and store the resulting rs, to then refine it further as necessary, this seems more in line with the spirit of DBIx::Class to me:

```
my $pages_rs = BUX::DB->rs('Page');

if ( my $faq_type = $self->param('faq_type') ){
    $pages_rs = $pages_rs->search({ 'me.faq_type' => $faq_type });
}

if ( my $search = $self->param('search') ){
    $pages_rs = $pages_rs->search({
        -or => [
            'me.title' => { ilike => "%$search%" },
            'me.text'  => { ilike => "%$search%" },
        ];
    });
}

my %attr = (
        join         => 'page_category',
        rows         => $self->param('limit'),
        offset       => $self->param('offset'),
        order_by     => { -desc => 'id' },
        result_class => 'BUX::Util::HashRefInflator',
        '+select'    => [ qw( page_category.name ) ],
        '+as'        => [ qw( category_name ) ],
);

$pages_rs = $pages_rs->search( undef, \%attr );

my @pages = $pages_rs->all; # This executes the query
```

Please keep in mind this is untested as I currently don't have an easy way of verifying this. If this does not help, feel free to comment and I'll try and fix whatever may be off.

EDIT: to not leave something in that is wrong, I've removed the (irrelevant) page count I put in.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not an answer to my question. With little modifications this code works perfectly and it's not the first time I see and use such style of creating conditions for DBIx::Class/SQL::Abstract. This case is very simple and I agree that it's not so necessary to use array as collector of all conditions but in larger tasks it becomes the only solution especcialy when we need to use the same field twice in one condition.

Comment: My actual qusetions is about recursion. In the case above in my code it seems like there **can not** be anything related to recursion however I got problems with performance and found log records about deep recursion. It's not a problem with rewritting the code - I already made it. I just want to understand how that case can cause recursion.

Comment: And answer to your question - **# why not scalar @pages, if you're fetching all, no need to query again?** Because of pagination. You can see that there are **rows** and **offset** attributes in `%attr` hash. So, you're wrong, it's not fetching all records.

Comment: Sry, I guess I should not be writing answers so late - since you're not paginating the count, that makes perfect sense.

I do not see how the query should cause deep recursion, though.
I don't know what your extension does, but I would try doing without and see where that goes.

Comment: I've put in a note about the `@cond`. I don't think it's correct to give a list, and I could easily see the parser getting confused.

Comment: `{ -and => \@cond }` - this surely will create a recursive data structure. And it is normal for perl. `{ -and => @cond }` must be similar to `unshift @array, 0;` and you can see that it is in my [demo](http://tpcg.io/fsis7t) but somehow it causes recursion in the code above. I can't understand how it can be.

Comment: Oh, and it's actually not a problem writing late. It's already appreciable that you tried to help. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your unshift comment. `{ -and => @cond }` will flatten `@cond` into the hashref, which is certainly not the same as unshifting the first element of `@cond`.

And why passing an arrayref would cause recursion is not clear to me at all.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. This `( -and => @cond )` is similar to `unshift @cond, '-and';`.

Comment: And about recursion - I made the same mistake - curly brackets. `@cond = ( -and => \@cond );` will create recursive data structure. Array will contain a reference to itself.

Comment: I see. Because you do `@cond = ( -and => \@cond )`. Well, don't do that. Just pass the arguments in sensibly, or, alternatively, build it as `@cond = ( -and => [ @cond ] )`. In neither of my suggested solutions do I build a reference to itself.

Comment: I described normal way of thinking about perl's syntax. Actual problem is not with that `@cond = ( -and => \@cond )`. Actual problem is that this code `@cond = ( -and => @cond );` crashed the server :) Without creating an array reference I got problems with recursion. And I still wonder how it can be. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: I disagree about the "normal way of thinking". However,
have you tried my approaches and found them not working?
What errors are you getting? 
Also, please read my note: you are simply not passing in your conditions the way they should be passed in, so it's not working.

Comment: Please, there is no need for another aproaches. As I said I already fixed that problem and it's working perfectly. Just replace `@cond` to `$cond`, do like that `push @{ $cond }, { condition1 => 'value1' };` and then `$cond = [ -and => $cond ]` and it will work. You can read this [article](http://search.cpan.org/~ilmari/SQL-Abstract-1.84/lib/SQL/Abstract.pm#Logic_and_nesting_operators) about logical operators in `SQL::Abstract` and figure out that it is everything fine in my code. There is one strange thing about recursion and I just want to find out how it can be - not to fix errors.

Comment: I was trying to point out that `{ -and => @cond }` is not the same as `[ -and => $cond]` which you're now saying is fine as if that's what you'd been doing all along. I do not see why SQL::Abstract is recursing now, the search / pagination you are doing *should* work fine as per your last comment.

Comment: It follows the problem has to be somewhere else. Have you tried without your BuxDB extension?

Comment: Of course I understand that this `{ -and => @cond }` is not the same with that `[ -and => $cond]`. I didn't use `{ -and => @cond }`. There is no such part in my code. Yes, I think you are right. The problem is somewhere else. No, I didn't check code without extension. Actually this extension is a wrapper and provides extension methods. I think I have to experiment with that code. Maybe I'll find something. Thank you.